# Anonymous method closures that capture the environment are not serializable

Tags: c#, botframework

I am getting the following error:

> Exception: anonymous method closures that capture the environment are not serializable, consider removing environment capture or using a reflection serialization surrogate: assistant.dialogs.Forms.SupportRequest+<>c__DisplayClass7_0'

when I try to set inner property in a Chain.

Could you please help?

My code:

```
public enum SystemSelection { SharePoint, BizTalk, Azure, Office365 };
public enum RequestType { Bug, SupportRequest, Question };
public enum Importance { Blocking, High, Medium, Low };

[Serializable]
class Declaration
{
    public string Type;
    public string Amount;
    public string Date;

    public static IForm<Declaration> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<Declaration>()
                .Message("Add a declaration")
                .Build();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class SupportRequest
{

    public SystemSelection? SystemSelection;
    public RequestType? RequestType;
    public Importance? Importance;

    public Declaration Declaration;

    public static IForm<SupportRequest> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<SupportRequest>()
                .Message("Welcome to the simple support bot!")
                .AddRemainingFields()
                .Build();
    }

    internal static IDialog<SupportRequest> MakeRootDialog3()
    {
        SupportRequest t = null;
        var dlg = Chain.ContinueWith(FormDialog.FromForm(SupportRequest.BuildForm),
                            async (context, res) =>
                            {
                                t = await res;
                                return Chain.ContinueWith<Declaration, SupportRequest>(FormDialog.FromForm(Declaration.BuildForm),
                                                            async (context2, res2) =>
                                                            {
                                                                t.Declaration = await res2;
                                                                return Chain.Return(t);
                                                            });
                            });

        return dlg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected since anonymous methods are not serializable and per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-general-problems#im-using-the-bot-builder-sdk-for-net-how-can-i-troubleshoot-issues-with-my-bot) you need to ensure all the dialogs are serializable:

> **Ensure that all dialogs are serializable**.
>   This can be as simple as using the [Serializable] attribute on your IDialog implementations. However, be aware that anonymous method closures are not serializable if they reference their outside environment to capture variables. The Bot Framework supports a reflection-based serialization surrogate to help serialize types that are not marked as serializable.

You will have to replace the `ResumeAfter<T>` continuation you are defining as an anonymous method with a non-anonymous one.

Alternatively, you can try registering the Reflection Serialization Surrogate by adding it to the Autofac container. In your global.asax, try adding this code:

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
{   
    builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());
});
```